# Polygon area calculation discrepancies using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, area, shape-area

I use the following code to calculate the areas of a multi-polygon shapefile. However, to validate these results, I calculate the polygon’ areas directly in table attribute by creating a new field and applying the formula: `$area`. I found discrepancies in calculated areas by both methods.

Does the `QgsDistanceArea` class consider the layer CRS (in my case I use EPSG:32632) and `$area` does not, that means the geographic WSG84 EPSG:4326 is considered by default?

```py
def area_poly(layer):
  L = []
  features = layer.getFeatures()
  d = QgsDistanceArea()
  d.setSourceCrs(layer.crs(), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())    
  d.setEllipsoid(QgsProject.instance().ellipsoid())
  for i, element in enumerate(features):
    for poly in element.geometry().asMultiPolygon():
        m = d.measurePolygon(poly[0])
        L.append((i, round(m,1))
  return L
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd show some output results. We don't know if you're talking about a 0.1% difference or a 100% difference. If it's a large difference, it is most likely due to the CRS interpretation.

Comment: The results are shown in the attached figure. The differences are not very significant 0.2%. Thank you for more clarifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the opposite - [`$area`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#area) will consider both the layer CRS and project ellipsoid setting. But your code does not, as creating a default constructed [`QgsDistanceArea`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDistanceArea.html) is not sufficient to get ellipsoid based measurements, and will currently be returning euclidean areas only.

You should revise your code to (for QGIS 3.x):

```py
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setSourceCrs(layer.crs(), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
d.setEllipsoid(QgsProject.instance().ellipsoid())
```

Comment: Many thanks ndawson for your clarifications, it works perfectly. However, I am confused for another issue: when I save the line layer (EPSG 32632) in another CSR (for example EPSG: 22391), the object’s length changes considerably: L_32632=68.7m and L_22391=82.5m. Why couldn't I have the same length? Many thanks in advance for more clarifications.

Comment: How are you measuring this? If it's euclidean (non-ellipsoidal) distances then different measurements are expected across different projections. If you're using ellipsoidal measurements, double check that the same ellipsoid is being used in both cases.

Comment: I apologize Ndawson, I did a mistake while constructing the layer. Now, it works perfectly. Many thanks